# Django form data not saving into databsae

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a  form on web app, using to get the data and store into database.
The problem is:
I am using different fields along with 2 Date Fields. When I removed the 2 date fields from the Model and Form, the form data stores easily into database but when added again into the Model and Form, it dose not save anything into database.

Model:

```
name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=50, help_text='Co-worker name.')
    email = models.EmailField('Email', help_text='Co-worker email.')
    address = models.TextField('Address', help_text='Co-worker address.')
    phone = models.CharField('Phone Number', max_length=20, help_text='Co-worker phone number.')
    companyName = models.CharField('Company Name', max_length=80, help_text='Co-worker company name.', null=True,
                                   blank=True)
    workingLocation = models.CharField('Working Location', max_length=50,
                                       help_text='Co-worker working '
                                                 'location.')
    workingShift = models.CharField('Working Shift', max_length=50, help_text='Co-worker working shift.', default='')
    workingSpace = models.CharField('Working Space', max_length=50, help_text='Co-worker working space.', default='')
    teamMembers = models.CharField('Team Members', max_length=15, help_text="Co-Worker's Team Size.", default='')
    coworkerPicture = models.ImageField('Co-Worker Picture', upload_to='../media/images/co-woker-pictures'
                                        , help_text='Co-worker Picture.', default='profile_pics/default.jpg', )
    joiningDate = models.DateField('Joining Date', help_text='Joining Date of Co-worker',default=date.today,
                                    )
    dob = models.DateField('Date of Birth', help_text='Date of Birth of Co-worker',  default=date.today,
```

View:

```
def Coworkers(request):
    # If user is not logged In
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('login')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = addCoWorkerForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Co-Worker added successfully.')
            return redirect('admin/co-workers')

   c = context = ({
    'form': form,
    })

   # Render the HTML template co_workers.html
    return render(request, 'dashboard/co_workers.html', c)
```

Form:

```
class addCoWorkerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control formInput',
        'placeholder': 'Name',
        'required': 'True'
    }))
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control formInput',
        'placeholder': 'Email',
        'required': 'True'

    }))
    address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control formInput',
        'placeholder': 'Address',
        'rows': '4'

    }))
    companyName = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control formInput',
        'placeholder': 'Company Name',

    }))
    phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control formInput',
        'placeholder': 'Phone Number',
        'required': 'True'
    }))
    CHOICES = [('Choose working location..', 'Choose working location..'),
               ('Islamabad', 'Islamabad'),
               ('Rawalpindi', 'Rawalpindi')]
    workingLocation = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.Select(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control formInput',
        'required': 'True',
    }))
    CHOICES = [('Choose working shift..', 'Choose working shift..'),
               ('Day Time', 'Day Time'),
               ('Night', 'Night')]
    workingShift = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.Select(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control formInput',
        'required': 'True',
    }))
    CHOICES = [('Choose working space..', 'Choose working space..'),
               ('Shared Space', 'Shared Space'),
               ('Private Room', 'Private Room')]
    workingSpace = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.Select(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control formInput',
        'required': 'True',
    }))
    teamMembers = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control formInput',
        'placeholder': 'Team Members',
        'required': 'True'
    }))
    coworkerPicture = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control formInput',
    }))
    joiningDate = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control formInput',
        'id': 'datePicker',
        'input_formats': ['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M']
    }))
    dob = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control formInput',
        'id': 'datePicker',
        'input_formats': ['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M']
    }))

       class Meta:
        model = CoWorker_Data
        fields = '__all__'
```

Please suggest me solution.

Comment: add your form code too

Comment: Okay. Let me add.

Comment: I am also using Django Updateview and due to this issue, its also not working.

Comment: try to add a else part and print(form.errors.as_data()) to the form valid part and try to submit with the date values. and check what error you are getting

Comment: Let me check both cases..

Comment: change the default value in date field to auto_now_add=True, or add timezone.now, import timezone from django utils

Comment: With Datefields It returns error, Validation Error: Enter a valid date.
Without Datefields it saves the data into database.

Comment: auto_now_add=True, or add timezone.now, not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `input_formats` is for [DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#datetimefield)  but you have defined the field as only [DateField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#datefield) so  change here like this:

```
  joiningDate = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control formInput',
        'id': 'datePicker',
        input_formats= settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS
    }))
```

EDIT: If you are defining the [date_input_format](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#date-format) in your settings.py then define it like this

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d/%m/%Y']
```

Note:`DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` in settings.py has no effect with `USE_I18N = True`.

Comment: Chnaged but no success. Then,

```
joiningDate = forms.DateField(input_formats=settings.input_formats, widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control formInput',
        'id': 'datePicker',
    }))

```

Comment: Yes: Enter a valid date for both datefields in CMD.

Comment: I entered input_formats = ['%d %B, %Y'] in setting.py and used in forms.

Comment: @GhulamHaider check my answer

Comment: Correct. Thank you very much for your support @arjun@Exprator